# ERROR: unused argument (output.results = TRUE)

Tags: r, output

This is how my data looks like:

```
> dput(head(GDP_NUTS2,5))
structure(list(Regiao = c("T", "N", "Ag", "C", "AML"), t2000 = c(12529.42964, 
10054.60679, 13045.59069, 10621.51789, 18104.36306), t2001 = c(13142.7713, 
10652.46712, 13920.41552, 11101.08412, 18865.55149), t2002 = c(13714.17406, 
11001.34917, 14612.37052, 11507.36163, 19812.29293), t2003 = c(13985.02689, 
11031.7278, 15137.89461, 11884.96687, 20165.68892), t2004 = c(14537.15966, 
11354.02317, 15479.68985, 12364.05053, 21068.05117), t2005 = c(15107.92333, 
11875.44359, 16237.49791, 12754.40299, 21829.31373), t2006 = c(15816.27567, 
12439.6426, 17046.29326, 13378.47797, 22714.25829), t2007 = c(16660.99538, 
13229.02402, 17981.40383, 14044.39707, 23847.44923), t2008 = c(16971.19746, 
13579.51144, 18226.74178, 14091.85326, 24347.83971), t2009 = c(16606.6617, 
13243.19054, 17038.45595, 13974.46502, 23794.44899), t2010 = c(16986.91604, 
13677.38358, 16976.83391, 14284.14565, 24119.66719), t2011 = c(16655.71238, 
13491.68626, 16347.69468, 14011.54637, 23503.1765), t2012 = c(15963.69251, 
13111.6173, 16059.51047, 13623.68635, 22118.01701), t2013 = c(16257.04222, 
13473.68717, 16301.87448, 13919.18355, 22337.24739), t2014 = c(16596.21219, 
13935.07757, 16974.57715, 14220.1043, 22491.62875), t2015 = c(17322.0514, 
14570.33755, 17851.78088, 14983.95312, 23101.89351), t2016 = c(18033.44444, 
15283.33044, 19251.57661, 15620.77307, 23800.20038), t2017 = c(19006.33518, 
16083.53849, 20893.19975, 16410.11278, 24938.22636), t2018 = c(19938.15583, 
17031.94867, 22131.96942, 17242.70015, 25974.24055), t2019 = c(20755.955, 
17712.44223, 23145.30242, 18045.54697, 26970.71178)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I'm using the "REAT" package to test the absolute beta convergence comparing years 2000 (t2000) and 2019 (t2019) with OLS (Ordinary Least Squares) estimation using function `betaconv.ols()`.

I've used this code: `betaconv.ols(GDP_NUTS2$t2000, 2000, GDP_NUTS2$t2019, 2019, output.results = TRUE)` I tried other version of the code but my major problem is the `output.results=TRUE` because I get always this error: `Error in betaconv.ols(GDP_NUTS2$t2000, 2000, GDP_NUTS2$t2019, 2019, output.results = TRUE) : unused argument (output.results = TRUE)`

I've been searching for alternatives of `output.results` but no success.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is `print.results` based on the `args` of the function

```
> args(betaconv.ols)
function (gdp1, time1, gdp2, time2, conditions = NULL, beta.plot = FALSE, 
    beta.plotPSize = 1, beta.plotPCol = "black", beta.plotLine = FALSE, 
    beta.plotLineCol = "red", beta.plotX = "Ln (initial)", beta.plotY = "Ln (growth)", 
    beta.plotTitle = "Beta convergence", beta.bgCol = "gray95", 
    beta.bgrid = TRUE, beta.bgridCol = "white", beta.bgridSize = 2, 
    beta.bgridType = "solid", print.results = FALSE) 
NULL
```

```
betaconv.ols(GDP_NUTS2$t2000, 2000, GDP_NUTS2$t2019, 2019, print.results = TRUE)
```

-output

```
Absolute Beta Convergence 
Model coefficients (Estimation method: OLS)
              Estimate  Std. Error   t value  Pr (>|t|)
Alpha     1.537689e-01 0.048509886  3.169847 0.05048663
Beta     -1.341938e-02 0.005137275 -2.612158 0.07953682
Lambda    7.110647e-04          NA        NA         NA
Halflife  9.748018e+02          NA        NA         NA
Model summary 
           Estimate  F value df 1 df 2    Pr (>F)
R-Squared 0.6946059 6.823372    1    3 0.07953682
```